# Snowflake DB : How to plot a Geospatial sphere feature in Snowflake?

Tags: geospatial, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, geography

Snowflake now supports geospatial datatype.It supports geographical features like point,line,Polygon.
But wanted to know ,whether it supports for spherical feature?
How to plot a spherical feature in Snowflake geospatial datatype?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Snowflake documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-geospatial.html) it only supports WGS84 (EPSG:4326), which does not have a z (height/elevation) coordinate, making it impossible to represent a sphere, which is a 3d shape. Approximating the 2d projection, a circle, should be somewhat possible.

A lot of geospatial engines have a function called `buffer` (or some variation thereof), which when performed on a point would give you an approximation of a circle. Depending on what you are doing, this might be what you need. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like Snowflake has a `buffer` function as of July 2020.

If all you need to do is detect whether a point `p` lies within a disc of radius `r` around a point `c`, you can use the `ST_DWITHIN` function to accomplish that goal. You can find the documentation for that function [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/st_dwithin.html). Note that you must supply your radius in meters.